# QuickApps CMS and menu change in theme

Tags: php, cakephp, menu, themes, quickapps-cms

I'm trying to make a new theme for [QuickApps CMS](http://www.quickappscms.org/eng/). When I try to echo:

```
<?php echo $this->Block->region('user-menu'); ?>
```

To render the user-menu in the new theme layout, it do two things:

1. Print out a title for the menu named "User Menu" while in the
   Default theme it does not print this title.
2. In addition it prints different HTML as follows

My New Theme output

```
<div id="qa-block-5" class="qa-block qa-block-unique qa-block-menu">

  <div id="block_5" class="block block-Menu delta-user-menu ">

       <h2> User Menu </h2>

         <div class="content">
            <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-22" class="first-item menu-item-22"><a href="/4test/quick-apps/user/my_account" target="_self"><span>My account</span></a>    </li>
            <li id="menu-item-23" class="last-item menu-item-23"><a href="/4test/quick-apps/user/logout" target="_self"><span>Logout</span></a> </li>
        </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

The Default Theme ouput

```
<div id="user-menu">
                    <div id="qa-block-5" class="qa-block qa-block-unique qa-block-menu">
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-22" class="first-item menu-item-22"><a href="/4test/quick-apps/user/my_account" target="_self"><span>My account</span></a>    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-23" class="last-item menu-item-23"><a href="/4test/quick-apps/user/logout" target="_self"><span>Logout</span></a> </li>
</ul>
</div>              </div>
```

I tried to find any elements that handles this HTML but I could not find. What I need to know is how to change the output of the menu according to my new theme? i.e change its HTML structure including styles class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to customize the output, your theme can implement the "theme_block" view element,
it will be used when rendering each block.

Here you can see "Default Theme" implementation:

https://github.com/QuickAppsCMS/QuickApps-CMS/blob/1.1/QuickApps/View/Themed/Default/Elements/theme_block.ctp

QuickApps uses a series of view elements for when rendering, if your theme do not implement any of this core's element are used by default. Here you can see a list of elements your theme may implement:

https://github.com/QuickAppsCMS/QuickApps-CMS-Docs/blob/1.x/eng/designers/themes.md#rendering-elements

Best regards!
/Chris

---

PS: BTW, there are big changes coming in v2.0 so stay tuned. For example blocks & regions are now objects, you can now do nifty things, for instance:

```
$this->region('main-menu')
    ->merge($this->region('other-region'))
    ->blockLimit(5);
```